# Grant permission to a sharpoint-online subsite

Tags: sharepoint-online, api

I'd like to grant permission to a subsite of sharepoint-online using the Sharepoint API. The subsite is created using the following parameters (I was using Power Automate - but in the end it is a API call):

```
_api/web/webinfos/add

{ 'parameters': 
    { '__metadata': 
        { 'type': 'SP.WebInfoCreationInformation' }, 
        'Url':'@{variables('SiteURL')}', 
        'Title':'@{variables('SubSiteTitle')}', 
        'Description':'Project Site', 
        'Language':'1031', 
        'WebTemplate':'STS#2', 
        'UseUniquePermissions':true
    } 
}
```

Where I've already broken the inheritance usind the "UseUniquePermissions" flag.

Nevertheless - what is the right API call to add an existing group to this new subsite?

Answer (score 0):

This article shows how to set custom permissions for a list. This process works the same for a subsite.

[Set custom permissions on a list by using the REST interface](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/set-custom-permissions-on-a-list-by-using-the-rest-interface)

[image]

```
// Change placeholder values before you run this code.
var siteUrl = 'http://server/site';
var listTitle = 'List 1';
var groupName = 'Group A';
var targetRoleDefinitionName = 'Contribute';
var groupId;
var targetRoleDefinitionId;

$(document).ready( function() {
  getTargetGroupId();
});

// Get the ID of the target group.
function getTargetGroupId() {
  $.ajax({
    url: siteUrl + '/_api/web/sitegroups/getbyname(\'' + groupName + '\')/id',
    type: 'GET',
    headers: { 'accept':'application/json;odata=verbose' },
    success: function(responseData) {
      groupId = responseData.d.Id;
      getTargetRoleDefinitionId();
    },
    error: errorHandler
  });
}

// Get the ID of the role definition that defines the permissions
// you want to assign to the group.
function getTargetRoleDefinitionId() {
  $.ajax({
    url: siteUrl + '/_api/web/roledefinitions/getbyname(\''
        + targetRoleDefinitionName + '\')/id',
    type: 'GET',
    headers: { 'accept':'application/json;odata=verbose' },
    success: function(responseData) {
      targetRoleDefinitionId = responseData.d.Id;
      breakRoleInheritanceOfList();
    },
    error: errorHandler
  });
}

// Break role inheritance on the list.
function breakRoleInheritanceOfList() {
  $.ajax({
    url: siteUrl + '/_api/web/lists/getbytitle(\'' + listTitle
        + '\')/breakroleinheritance(true)',
    type: 'POST',
    headers: { 'X-RequestDigest':$('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val() },
    success: deleteCurrentRoleForGroup,
    error: errorHandler
  });
}

// Remove the current role assignment for the group on the list.
function deleteCurrentRoleForGroup() {
  $.ajax({
    url: siteUrl + '/_api/web/lists/getbytitle(\'' + listTitle
        + '\')/roleassignments/getbyprincipalid(' + groupId + ')',
    type: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'X-RequestDigest':$('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val(),
      'X-HTTP-Method':'DELETE'
    },
    success: setNewPermissionsForGroup,
    error: errorHandler
  });
}

// Add the new role assignment for the group on the list.
function setNewPermissionsForGroup() {
  $.ajax({
    url: siteUrl + '/_api/web/lists/getbytitle(\'' + listTitle
        + '\')/roleassignments/addroleassignment(principalid='
        + groupId + ',roledefid=' + targetRoleDefinitionId + ')',
    type: 'POST',
    headers: { 'X-RequestDigest':$('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val() },
    success: successHandler,
    error: errorHandler
  });
}

function successHandler() {
  alert('Request succeeded.');
}

function errorHandler(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
  alert('Request failed: ' + xhr.status + '\n' + thrownError + '\n' + xhr.responseText);
}
```

**Update to address comment:**

It does not appear that you can use the AddRoleAssignment method when targeting a site in the same way you can when targeting a list. I'm not sure why that would be.

I tried to find a sample or some documentation that showed how to add a role assignment to a subsite using the REST API but I came up empty. The best I can offer is a sample that shows how to do it using the JavaScript Object Model (JSOM).

In the code snippet below the group Demo 3 Members is being given Edit permission in the subsite with the URL `/sites/Demo3/TestSubSite`.

```
function addRoleAssignment() {
  var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext("https://robwindsortest985.sharepoint.com/sites/Demo3/TestSubSite");  
  var web = clientContext.get_web();

  var group = web.get_siteGroups().getByName("Demo 3 Members");
  var roleDefinition = web.get_roleDefinitions().getByName("Edit");

  var bindingCollection = SP.RoleDefinitionBindingCollection.newObject(clientContext);   
  bindingCollection.add(roleDefinition);

  var roleAssignments = web.get_roleAssignments();  
  roleAssignments.add(group, bindingCollection);

  clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
    function(sender, args) {
      alert("Role assignment added");
    },
    function(sender, args) {
      alert(args.get_message());
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: On a list I would use the API call like this: _api/lists/getByTitle('ListTitle')/items(ItemNumber)/roleassignments/addroleassignment(principalid=XX,roleDefId=XXX). This works for me.
If I use the same for a subsite it does not work. I assume there is something else to address the desired subsite?

Comment: @Christoph I updated my answer to address your comment. Sorry for any confusion my original answer may have caused.